# Calling Method of class within it

Tags: c#-4.0

// What is the technical reason behind this scenarios..?

Comment: Answer one question: When should the method be executed when written into the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method call [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173143.aspx) *can not* be part of a `class` [declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691107%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but only *within* [Function members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691334%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) declarations scope, such as Methods, Properties, Constructors etc.

For example:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private void SayHelloWorld()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Hello World!");
    }

    public void CallSayHelloWorldMethod()
    {
       this.SayHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

At the above example you can see that I call the `SayHelloWorld` method within the `CallSayHelloWorldMethod` metod.

**Update:**

The closest thing I can think of in your case is to use the `class`'s [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) where your method call will be executed as soon as you'll instantiate your class:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    //The class constructor
    public ExampleClass()
    {
       this.SayHelloWorld();
    }

    private void SayHelloWorld()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

And when you instantiating it, it will be immediately called:

```
//Your method call will be executed here
ExampleClass exampleClass  = new ExampleClass();
```

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please tell me y exactly they didn't implemented that functionality (Method call statement as part of a class). i mean the logic behind that. because i learned programming by understanding the deepest part of it. so i'm little curious to know the reason behind this too... i do believe there will be a logical explanation behind this.

Comment: @prasobkumarkp When do yo expect your method's call to be executed if it is part of the class definition level only? I can assume that you want it to be executed as soon as the class is being instantiated, and for this you should call it in the class's constructor which is executed as soon as you use your class (object). See my update in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a statement other than a declaration directly inside the class - rather than within a method. When did you expect the method to get called?

Basically *all* you can have directly within a type is a bunch of declarations - methods, variables, constructors, events, nested types etc. Method calls (or any other statements) which aren't part of a declaration have to be written within methods, constructors etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems... This won't even compile as you are trying to call the method obj.m1() in the class definition.

```
A obj = new A();  
obj.m1(); // Why this code wont work??? --> This must be inside a method
```

When you create an instance of a class it will create a new member variable called obj which is an instance of A --> A obj = newA() above;

You will now be able to call obj's methods as in your second example.

Also, in order to get this to compile you will need to fix the m2 method:

```
public void m2() { //--> should have a curly brace 
   obj.m1(); // But This will work.
}
```